# Moduli space for Riemann surfaces with boundaries and open string loop diagrams

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, mathematical-physics, topology, moduli

I'm searching for information on the moduli space for Riemann surfaces with boundaries, like the ones used to compute open string loop diagrams. I found a huge lot of info for the case without boundaries (*i.e.* closed strings), but haven't found anything beyond spaces with two boundaries (the annulus).

So, the moduli space of the disk is a point, of the annulus is the half-line, what about a pair of pants? or spaces with even more holes?